# Is there any method or else to order by datatable with string values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example field name status have 3 fix values in there rows, now I want first 'Pending' values then 'Approved' and then 'Rejected' values in row.

I tried this query

```
qry = "SELECT * FROM Table_Name ORDER BY status dsc"
```

Comment: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN status = 'Pending' THEN 0 ELSE WHEN status = '...' THEN 1 ELSE  .... END`

Comment: Add a numeric column where you specify the order of these strings (if you have many of them)

Answer (score 0):

Use `case` or `iif` in your `order by` clause:

```
SELECT * -- Better specify column names here
FROM Table_Name
ORDER BY IIF([status] = 'Pending', 0, 1), IIF([status] = 'Approved', 0, 1), [status];
```

If there's a large list of values that you want to apply a specific order, you better add a numeric column that specifies this order:

```
SELECT * -- Better specify column names here
FROM Table_Name
ORDER OrderByColumn;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE WHEN SYNTAX

```
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
    ELSE result
END
```

In your case, I suggest to use this SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name ORDER BY 
    (CASE
        WHEN status = 'Pending' THEN 0
        WHEN status = 'Approved' THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END) dsc
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem in sql using condition in order by area
example
SELECT * FROM Table_Name ORDER BY CASE WHEN status = 'Pending' THEN '1' WHEN status = 'Approved' THEN '2' WHEN status = 'Rejected' THEN '3' ELSE status END ASC